# Inconsistent rate of growth with em values

Tags: html, css

For years now, I thought that I know enough about differences between different types of values in css, that I can make stylesheets with some level of confidence. Well, until this day at least.

While choosing the right font sizes for a header on my website, I discovered something odd about the rate of growth of font size, when increasing em values.

When emulating smaller screens, in some circumstances, changing em from 1.0 to 1.4 does very little to increase the actual font size, but then changing from 1.4 to 1.5 makes it 2 times bigger. Why is that?

I'm using this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="z2.css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
                <h1>Some text</h1>
                <p>Some longer text, with many lines, very long. Like, thesis long.
REEEALLLYY LONG TEXT. Long. Not hyperbolizing. Just loooooong teeeext. A big blob of long text. I just realized I could have just pasted Lorem Ipsum sonet here. Whatever...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this css:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2.7em;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    float:right;
}
```

This is what output looks like when emulating a **screen with 395 px width**:
[image: Medium header, then small sized font]

Now, changing `<p>`'s `font-size` from **1.0 to 1.1** does this:[image]

And then, changing it to **2.2** does this (nearly nothing): [image]

I'm very confused by this. I realize that this is probably just because of the font scaling. But when I:

- change the length of text inside `<p>` (add just one more letter to it)
- set `<p>`'s float to none

the actual size of the font on 1.0 em goes way up. Why?

Btw. I was using Chrome DevTools for this.

Comment: Maybe some browser plugin you have installed like Stylish that changes your styles? Looks totally fine to me in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8fc65thy/ I was able to remove float properties and change font-sizes at will and it seemed to be consistent.

Comment: @Paul : I reproduced it in a incognito tab - nothing changed. The thing with js fiddle is that it isn't scaling the font with the screen resolution like dev tools' emulator does. You need to emulate the screen width to observe this, not just shrink the container the text is in. I don't really have anything with screen so small on me right now, but since I will probably want to use such resolutions with RaspberryPi in the near future... well, let's just say it rubs me the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `viewport` meta inside your document's `head`.

Add something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Now you'll find that the mobile display size renders your `font-size` properly and changing sizes will make sense once again.

This might help you better understand what is happening in your current situation:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml